# Configure western digital essential 3TB to work with boxee box

Tags: external-hard-drive, boxee

I have a new western digital "my book elements" 3TB external harddrive. When I plug it in via USB to my boxee box it is not recognized.

Based on feedback from boxee forums I have tried:

1. GPT partitioning it.
2. Changing sector size to 512.
3. Creating 2 - 1.5tb partitions.

None of these solutions cause the boxee box to recognize the drive. Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: Does the Boxee have latest firmware?

Comment: Yes it has the latest official firmware: 1.5.1.23735-b6a5be1